# Show that $\frac{\mathbb{P}(B \mid A)}{\mathbb{P}(C \mid A)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(B)}{\mathbb{P}(C)} \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)}{\mathbb{P}(A \mid C)}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Show that

$\frac{\mathbb{P}(B \mid A)}{\mathbb{P}(C \mid A)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(B)}{\mathbb{P}(C)} \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)}{\mathbb{P}(A \mid C)}$.

What I've done so far:

$\frac{P(B \mid A)}{P(C \mid A)}=\frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)} \frac{P(A)}{P(C \cap A)}=\frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(C \cap A)}$

But how do I proceed from here? Am I missing some obvious equivalence? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(B \cap A) =\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)$ and $\mathbb{P}(C \cap A) = \mathbb{P}(C)\mathbb{P}(A \mid C)$ though I would use Bayes theorem to say says $\mathbb{P}(B \mid A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$ and $\mathbb{P}(C \mid A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(C)\mathbb{P}(A \mid C)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$.  Assuming everything is positive, just divide one by the other and cancel the $\mathbb{P}(A)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to finish it. Method 1 is to divide and multiply the expression you got by $\mathbb{P}(B)$ and $\mathbb{P}(C)$ to get
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(B\cap A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}\frac{\mathbb{P}(C)}{\mathbb{P}(C\cap A)}\frac{\mathbb{P}(B)}{\mathbb{P}(C)}.$$
This could be then finished by changing the first and second fractions to conditional probabilities.

Second method would be to simplify the right side to the same expression. You could argue that
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(B)}{\mathbb{P}(C)}\frac{\mathbb{P}(A|B)}{\mathbb{P}(A|C)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(B)}{\mathbb{P}(C)}\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\mathbb{P}(C)}{\mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{P}(A\cap C)},$$
and then do the cancelation to get the same expression as you got for the left side.